# Select a Valid Choice. 0 is not one of the available choices

Tags: django

```
TYPE1 = 0
TYPE2 = 1

OPEN_TYPES = (
    (TYPE1, _(u"Test")),
    (TYPE2, _(u"Test2")),
)
```

models:

```
models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=OPEN_TYPES)
```

I have this error if I try to add object in admin panel:

> Select a Valid Choice. 0 is not one of the available choices

How to fix it?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

You're using integer values with a `CharField`. You have to either use the values `'0'` and `'1'` or change it to an `IntegerField`.

Answer (score 1):

Use a default value also that will work!